# Difference between Salesforce Communities and Chatter Communities

Tags: chatter, community

Can someone explain me the difference between Salesforce Communities and Chatter Communities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That way it is branded can be a bit confusing, but [Salesforce Communities](https://www.salesforce.com/communities/overview/) and [Chatter Communities](http://www.salesforce.com/uk/chatter/features/communities/) are ultimately the same thing. There are [different editions and pricing](https://www.salesforce.com/communities/overview/#Pricing) around a Customer Community and Partner Community, but that is more around pricing and some functionality differences.

Some key information:

> **What is Salesforce Communities?**
>
> Salesforce Communities is an online platform that enables rich
>   collaboration between employees, customers, partners, suppliers and
>   distributors. Organizations can create fully-branded public or private
>   communities that connect members directly with each other – and with
>   relevant content, data and business processes. Salesforce Communities
>   is the only community platform that combines the power of social with
>   mobile participation, trusted security, and direct connection to
>   business processes.
>
> **What types of communities does Salesforce support?**
>
> Salesforce provides two general types of communities that can be used
>   for a broad variety of purposes, from customer service to marketing or
>   engagement of resellers, suppliers and partners.
>
> *Customer Communities* deliver rich collaboration, mobile access and consistent branding for even the largest groups. For example, a
>   service community enables customers to answer questions for other
>   customers, quickly find the information they need, or work with
>   service reps to resolve issues – decreasing time to resolution while
>   increasing engagement and loyalty.
>
> *Partner Communities* provide even greater ties to business process along with the added power of role-based security to segment the data
>   that’s been shared with different members. For example, partner
>   communities enable companies to manage reseller relationships by
>   keeping some lead and funding information private, but enabling
>   collaborative selling between partners, leading to more engaged
>   partners and increased deal flow.
>
> **What are the key features of Salesforce Communities?**
>
> No other communities platform offers the same combination of
>   capabilities along with deep integration into business process. Key
>   Communities features include:
>
> *Business Process Integration:* members can create and collaborate on support cases, sales opportunities or campaigns from within the
>   community
>
> *Social Collaboration:* members can interact, collaborate on goals and form groups to support their interests
>
> *Branding/Customization:* companies can design their community to match their brand and website look and feel. Content and navigation
>   structure is highly customizable.
>
> *Mobility:* members can access the community from any device, anywhere
>
> *Social Intelligence:* relevant content and resources are suggested to each member based on their interests and behavior
>
> *Security & scalability:* leveraging the trusted Salesforce platform, all data and member information is always safe -- no matter how many
>   members you have
>
> **If I don’t use Chatter, can I still use Communities?**
>
> Yes. Communities functionality is not dependent on the use of Chatter.
>   You can still get the branding and mobile benefits of the solution
>   along with other collaboration elements such as Ideas and Q & A.

- [Salesforce FAQ around Communities](http://www.salesforce.com/uk/chatter/communities/faq/)
- [Communities Data Sheet](https://secure2.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_Communities.pdf)